# IntelliJ Scala does not work anymore after El Capitan upgrade

Tags: java, macos

After I have updated to El Capitan I am having problems in running a Scala project with IntelliJ.

When I run it I obtain the following error:

> Error:Cannot run program "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/donbeo/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/compile-server"): error=2, No such file or directory

I think I have to specify where Java is or something like that.

It was working before.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the system version of Java 6 is installed, it gets removed when you upgrade.

For applications that still rely on it, you will need to reinstall it.

Download the [official Apple installer](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) and install it. Your program should then work as expected.

**Edit:** Optionally, inspect your project settings and see if you configure your project to use a newer version of the Java SDK, such as 8u60.